# Say "hello" when Twilio call connected

Tags: python-3.x, twilio, azure-cognitive-services, mu-law

I have a websocket in python Flask that listens to a twilio call. When the call is started I want to say "hello" here is the code.

```
     if data['event'] == "start":
        
        speakBytes = speaker.speak("Hello") // using micrsoft cognitive service to convert the text to bytes
        convertedBytes = ap.lin2ulaw(speakBytes.audio_data,1)
        ws.send(responseString.format(base64.b64encode(convertedBytes), str(data['streamSid'])))
```

But the above is not working. I checked microsoft cognitive services speech sunthesizer returns the bytes in WAV format so I have used `lin2ulaw` form python `audioop` module.

Need help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks like you are correctly creating the audio to send to the [Twilio Media Stream](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/stream), however I don't think you are sending the correct format.

Twilio Media Streams expect a media message to be a JSON object with the following properties:

- event: the value "media"
- streamSid: the SID of the stream
- media: an object with a "payload" property that then contains the base64 encoded mulaw/8000 audio

Something like this might work:

```py
message = {  
  "streamSid": data['streamSid'],  
  "event": "media",  
  "media": {
    "payload": base64.b64encode(convertedBytes)
  }
}  
       
# Serializing json   
json_object = json.dumps(message)

ws.send(json_object)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Twilio to connect the number then you'll need to reply with [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml) to the call:

```
from twilio.twiml.voice_response import VoiceResponse
response = VoiceResponse()
response.say('Hello')
return str(response)
```

See the doc of [`<Say></Say`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say).

If you want to use the `.wav` you created then you would need to save it somewhere accessible (e.g. an Amazon S3 bucket) and then you can use TwiML [`<Play></Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/play).

Comment: Yes...this works for rest point..but I am using websocket to listen to the call stream..where this doesnot seem to work

Comment: The author wants to play the base64 encoded stream over the socket. They are not using TwiML.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers everyone. The solution turned out to be a small change.

I had to change `ap.lin2ulaw(speakBytes.audio_data,1)` to `ap.lin2ulaw(speakBytes.audio_data,4)` and it worked fine. It seems to be the compatibility of microsoft text to speech and twilio formats.

Comment: Ah, glad you got it sorted out!